# How to create BarChar that contain in each series one element (Bar) in javafx

Tags: javafx

I created a Bar char but there is a big gap between the bars (I think it's because I use one element in each series). I tried setBarGap() but it doesn't change anything. here is what i do : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBvgz.png? and here is an example of what i want : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JlCK.png

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> answer = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
         for(int i=1;i<9;i++){
                               ....
                               ...
                               ...
             XYChart.Series<String, Number> series6 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();

                 series6.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(String.valueOf(i), 2*i));
answer.add(series6);
         }
         XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();

                series1.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>(">8",rs2.getInt(1)));
                answer.add(series1);

            return answer;
```

Comment: Calm down.  I'll get to it.  Don't delete your question and re-ask it, edit it to make it more answerable.  If you must know, I haven't tried because you've posted no code.  Even if your non-working example isn't what you want, post the code so I don't have to type so much in order to fix it.  I just haven't had time to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code but it's not enough to compile.

Comment: I think I see your problem, you're adding multiple series with different values for the categories (1 -> >8) .  That won't work, maybe explain what you're trying to accomplish by using multiple series.  I figured the series were so you could get a legend, but if it's just for different colors, then you can style each bar in css.

Comment: no its not for different colour, it for different value(each series has 1 value), here is an example of what I try to do : http://www.snapsurveys.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bar_2d8.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you add more than one category for all data series.  If one data series is named "1", and the other is named "2" and these are added to different series then the layout needs to save room in each category's group of bars for the missing category.  Like there's a space in "2" group for "1" bars, but you haven't added any.

Make sure you never add more than one category - they all have to have the same value.  Since it seems you're using different series for the color and legend, then just don't name the categories.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String,Number> bc = new BarChart(xAxis,yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Frequency of visit");
        bc.setLegendSide(Side.RIGHT);
        //if you want axis labels
        xAxis.setLabel("");       
        yAxis.setLabel("");

        bc.getData().addAll(makeSerie("daily",20),
                            makeSerie("twice a week",30),
                            makeSerie("weekly",40),
                            makeSerie("monthly",50));

        xAxis.setVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        bc.setBarGap(20);

        Scene scene  = new Scene(bc);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    //just to save typing
    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> makeSerie(String name, Number value){
        return new XYChart.Series(name,
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(new XYChart.Data("", value)));
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know that sample, but it’s not what I'm trying to do. In that example, the same value (austria) is attributed to different series (1, 2, 3). but what I want to attributed different value (austria,france,us) to series(1,2,3). Here is what I get if I do that: http://i.imgur.com/oJDQVL0.png

Comment: You can't do it like that. It's like I mentioned, you're trying to use series for the color and legend. So name the series instead of the data